# Laravel Auth not working, everything seems to be correct

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

here is my code below for controller...

```
    if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){

  //echo 'dfdf';
  //exit;
        return Redirect::to('mydata');
    }
```

it displays `dfdf` if i uncomment that...so it means Auth is fine.. right?? well here is my routes.php code...

```
 Route::get('mydata', function()
 {
   return View::make('mydata');})->before('auth');
```

even this works...if i remove `->before('auth');` from routes.php
    public function doLogin()
    {

```
    return Redirect::to('mydata');
    exit;
     }
```

`that means even router is fine right?`

routes work without logging in if i remove `before('auth');` ,that seems even routes is fine,, then what the problem with `return Redirect::to('mydata');` why is it not redirecting??it stucks on the login page even after authentication...

Comment: @pc-shooter yes it works then...but if i remove `before('auth');` let me update my question..

Comment: @pc-shooter it is of no use to redirect to data without using `before('auth');` in that case i dont even have to do login right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited after comments:**

In the controller, change your redirect to `::intended`:

```
if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
    return Redirect::intended('mydata');
}
```

From the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users):

> The `Redirect::intended` function will redirect the user to the URL they
>   were trying to access before being caught by the authentication
>   filter. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the
>   intended destination is not available.

The API:

```
intended(string $default = '/', int $status = 302, array $headers = array(), bool $secure = null)
```

And you don't need to add the `->before('auth')` to your `View`call, because you're redirecting to `mydata` *only* if the `Auth::attempt` returns `true`.

So change your route to: **EDIT after comments** Thx to  Juan Antonio Orozco for pointing at this lack!!

```
Route::get('mydata', array('before' => 'auth', function() {
      return View::make('mydata');
});
```

And, BTW, after a `return` it's unneccesary to add an `exit`, because the interpreter has already left the function with the `return` command, so it wouldn't even be executed.

Comment: Passing the 'before' filter to the route attributes and calling the before() method are the same.

Comment: ammm but what if the user guess the url of the route that is suposed to be  for logged in users only?, that page should be protected against unauthenticad users

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco Thx for pointing at. You're right! Edited my answer. If you're the downvoter, could u reverse taht pls?

Answer (score 1):

You can use auth filter in route like this.

---

```
Route::get('mydata', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{

  return View::make('mydata');

}));
```